# Galaxy Core Prime: Gallery warns about low space, but fails to delete

Tags: applications, internal-storage, photos

When I try and look at my pictures in gallery, there's a warning "There is not enough space (-1751 MB) in your device memory. Delete some files". So, I hit "okay" and it takes me to my files, and pictures. I try to delete the pictures and it says "deletion failed", why?

Answer (score -2):

Take out the memory chip from your device and plug into a pc using a memory card reader....and then delete the files